# Is it possible to change the author of a problem on mathoverflow?

Tags: support, feature-request, editing, user-accounts, multiple-accounts

By a mistake I have written the problem [Is "weakly good" series in a finite-dimensional Banach space "good"?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281948/is-weakly-good-series-in-a-finite-dimensional-banach-space-good) from my account instead of writing it from the account of Lviv Scottish Book (https://mathoverflow.net/users/105651/lviv-scottish-book). This problem already has some upvotes and some comments.

Is it possible to rewrite it to the user Lviv Scottish Book without destroing the upvotes and comments?

Comment: Based on what's written here, it seems that ownership of post is changed only in serious circumstances: [Change ownership of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283039) and [Move post to different user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290225). Of course, there is also option to make a new post and ask moderators for merging. (That would preserve the comments, but not the votes. Still, before doing that it would be better to know what moderators think about this.)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, site moderators do not have the ability to perform an action which meets all these conditions. I would suggest writing a letter to Community Management (see the 'contact us' when you scroll to the bottom of the page) and explain the situation, pointing them to this post. (If a CM sees this comment: the OP here is a trusted user.)

Comment: Alternatively, because the question does not yet have an upvoted answer, you could simply delete it and then re-ask it with the other account. You would of course lose the 8 upvotes, and you would have to manually copy the information from the comments. The "meta" effect should make up for lost votes.

Comment: @jeq This is too simple solution (with the lost of 8 upvotes).

Comment: I suppose the reason you want to change the owner *in this specific case* is that there is a separate user for Lviv Scottish Book problems and you would like to have list of questions from Lviv Scottish Book visible somewhere in this user's profile. If some of those questions were posted by different users, a simple way to create such list would be using [the favorites tab](https://mathoverflow.net/users/105651/lviv-scottish-book?tab=favorites) of this user.